# dial in Vs. dial in on

Tags: prepositions

I have found such an example:

Check the date, time, the phone number to dial in on, and the right code to access the conference call

Tell me please how I should treat "on".
Is it the part of a collocation?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You don't actually need ***either*** preposition here *(dial **in + on**)*), but it's not uncommon to add a superfluous ***on*** in such contexts. Even when this involves repeating the ***same*** preposition, as in *When I'm working from home, I **log on on** my laptop* (many people use ***log on*** rather than ***log in*** there, and most of them probably wouldn't really even *notice* the preposition duplication).

Comment: Thank you for help!